# Finding older dates in strings in python 3

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am writing a program which deletes directories with YYYY-MM-DD dates as names. I am stuck writing a method for this which creates a list of pathnames of folders to be deleted. The criteria for adding them to this list is the age of the date in the folder name.

I am having trouble with getting the program to identify these older dates.

```
import os
import sys
import datetime
import config #this is by me

global archivePath # config value: "/archive/"
global archiveForDays # config value: 14

archivePath = config.archivePath
archiveForDays = config.archiveForDays

def getDestruDirList():
    # This method creates a list of files for deletion.

    archiveList = os.listdir(archivePath) #get list of archive directorires
    deletionList = []                     #create list for deletion

    for dateStr in archiveList:
        skip = False
        if (not dateStr == "current"):
            dateVar = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
            if dateVar.date < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=archiveForDays):
                deletionList.append(archivePath + dateStr) #add full pathname to deletion list
                print("Revision " + dateVar.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + " to be deleted.")

    return deletionList
```

Testing this doesn't work, and I am not very familiar with dates and have never seen this error before. Tests on the method fail as follows...

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep  9 2016, 06:04:18)
[GCC 4.9.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cleaner
>>> cleaner.getDestruDirList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/archive-scripts/cleaner.py", line 22, in getDestruDirList
    if dateVar.date < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=archiveForDays):
TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() < datetime.datetime()
```

Edit: I am more sure about the TypeError problem but I am not sure what to do about it, and am stuck.

Comment: `if dateVar.date < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=archiveForDays):`

In above condition you missed to call the function, dateVar.date(),

Also then you will be comparing date and datetime, so you might need to change `datetime.datetime.now()` to `datetime.datetime.now().date()`

Comment: Is ```dateVar.date``` a method/function/callable?  Should it be ```dateVar.date()```?  Or possibly just use ```dateVar```.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some syntax errors leading to the use of the wrong types. At some point researching a solution, I might have made the mistake of looking at a Python2 example. Here is a finished unit-tested method which produces a list of directories named after dates more than a certain number of days old.

```
def getDestruDirList():
    # This method creates a list of files for deletion.

    archiveList = os.listdir(archivePath) #get list of archive directorires
    deletionList = []                     #create list for deletion

    for dateStr in archiveList:
        skip = False
        if (not dateStr == "current"):
            dateVar = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
            if dateVar.date() < datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=archiveForDays):
                deletionList.append(archivePath + dateStr) #add full pathname to deletion list
                print("Revision " + dateVar.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + " to be deleted.")

    return deletionList
```